# архитектура программы и множественное наследование

Tags: архитектура, проектирование

Столкнулся с множественным наследованием при проектировании архитектуры (визуализация процесса).

В целом, есть бункеры, дозаторы, корзина и конвейер. Все они должны отображаться на форме. Предпочел наследование от *Widget*, чтобы не делегировать кучу его методов (*show*, *hide*, *setColor*, *move* и т.п. методы, которые могут понадобиться для анимации).

Я условно разделил все объекты на два типа:

- *Container* (имеет номер и содержит информацию о своем содержимом, но не имеет состояния, например *HopperDst*, просто "бочка", в которой что-то лежит)
- *Device* (которое работает под напряжением и содержит информацию о предупреждениях, кодах ошибок, просадках напряжения, и т.п.).

Но появляется проблема, когда объект ведет себя и как контейнер, и как девайс (например, бункер может открываться и закрываться, на диаграмме *HopperSrc*, *Batcher*). В этом случае множественное наследование помогло бы избежать дублирования кода с обработкой *warning*, но зато дважды унаследует от *Widget*.

В итоге: очевидно, что с этим нужно что-то делать, но не совсем очевидно, что именно. Можно ли как-то изменить архитектуру, чтоб избежать подобных проблем?

P.S. под большой красной стрелкой я имел ввиду место наследования, которое породит проблему. На текущий момент оно не наследуется, поэтому продублировал поля и методы в *HopperSrc*, *Batcher* и *Device*.

[image: диаграмма классов]

Comment: Вероятно, вместо наследования следует применить композицию/агрегирование.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я думал об композиции, но `предпочел наследование от Widget, чтобы не делегировать кучу его методов`. Ведь в случае композиции нужно будет создавать метод вызова для каждого метода *widget*, который нужно будет использовать из потомка, не так ли?

Comment: @Bogdan Интерфейсы попробуйте.

Comment: @Dmitry, используя интерфейс, нужно будет в каждом реализующем интерфейс классе, как это ни странно, писать код реализации интерфейса. А что, если этот код везде одинаков? `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+v`?

Comment: @Bogdan Если код должен быть одинаковым, а разным не может быть в принципе, я бы сказал, что это должен быть код общего предка. У вас же и `Container`, и `Device` наследуются от одного класса?

Comment: @Dmitry, да, они от одного предка. Но предок - класс виджета на форме (groupbox если быть конкретным). Суть в том, что некоторые объекты должны иметь свойства **только контейнера**, некоторые **только устройства**, а некоторые **и контейнера, и устройства**. Отсюда складывается вывод, что один предок для всех классов, не совсем верное решение. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему путем перемещения `Device` и `Container` на тот же уровень иерархии, на котором расположен `Widget`, и теперь они не наследуют `Widget`. В результате если объект является и устройством, и контейнером, то объявление класса выглядит следующим образом:

```
class SomeObject : public Widget, public Device, public Container
{ /* ... */ };
```

**Это помогло мне** избавиться от проблемы ромба при множественном наследовании, т.к. `Device` и `Container` не имеют базовых классов.

Также: **Я отказался от использования композиции** (как было предложено в комментариях), потому что:

1. `Device` это не часть `SomeObject`.
2. `SomeObject` это один из возможных устройств.
3. `SomeObject` это один из возможных виджетов.
4. `SomeObject` это один из возможных контейнеров.

**Что я получил**: Container/Device методы объявлены и определены только один раз в моей программе (например сеттеры и геттеры для свойств) и все их дочерние объекты могут использовать их *из коробки* без всякого делегирования.